# How to prevent automatic top-scrolling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm a beginner in Javascript, I created a form with a button that allows the user to add new fields. the problem is that each time the user clicks on the button and the HTML is added, the page scrolls to top automatically.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('test4321').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', b);"
```

how can I, please, prevent that? For a better user experience.

thank you in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

From what you described it would appear page is reloading.

You have to prevent the page default.

```
document.querySelector('yourButtonHere').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();

document.getElementById('test4321').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', b);

});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the page doesn't refresh : after adding the new input fields html,  the page scroll to top.

Comment: Can you show more code? Are you using a scrollTo in the code anywhere?